# How do you change a variable while in a different if statement? (C++)

Tags: c++, scope

I am making a program where you enter something and it detects it. then it changes a variable. But the problem is that I need to access the new variable contents outside of the if statement. Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        while (1)
        {
                string dir = "C:/";
                string line;
                string afterPrint;
                string prompt = "| " + dir + " |> ";
                cout << prompt;
                getline(cin, line);

                stringstream ss(line);
                while (ss)
                {
                        string command;
                        ss >> command;
                        transform(command.begin(), command.end(), command.begin(), ::tolower);// Command, but lowercase
                        if (command == "cd")
                        {
                                string dir;
                                if (ss >> dir)
                                {
                                        cout << "Directory: " << dir << "\n"; // it changes here
                                        string prompt = "| " + dir + " |> ";  // and here
                                }
                        }
                        else if (command == "c:" || command == "c:\\")
                        {
                                cout << "Directory: " << dir << "\n";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                cout << "error\n";
                        }
                        break;
                }
                // but I need it here (when the loop restarts)
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply declare the variable outside the loop:

```
std::string dir;
while (ss)
{
  ...
  if (ss >> dir)
  {
    ...
  }
}
//use dir here
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare command above the second loop. Then inside the second loop reset command = "" before placing contents of stringstream